# Select COUNT > 10K em C# e SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-select, count

Gostaria de fazer select em registros maiores que 10 mil e excluir após.

```
select count (FuncionarioID) > 10000 FROM FuncionarioLog;
```

Como devo fazer select corretamente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode sempre fazer da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
            SELECT  *
                ,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Registo ASC) AS Linha
            FROM    Tabela) X
WHERE   Linha <= 10000
```

No `ORDER BY Registo ASC` devemos substituir o `Registo` pela coluna pela qual queremos ordenar, ou seja, aquela por onde os registos serão ordenados de forma a gerar o número da linha (`ROW_NUMBER`).

Ao invés de `Tabela` teremos, como é óbvio, que colocar o nome da nossa tabela.

---

Mais informação sobre o uso do **`ROW_NUMBER`** na documentação da Microsoft: [ROW_NUMBER (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Show !! Ajudou. Abraços

Comment: Perfeito :)! Aproveite para dar um UP na resposta?